# jquery compare elements with serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare the value of a form element with it's default text (set via the title attribute).  If the VALUE == TITLE, change the value to a zero length string.  However, I can't seem to make it work.  I'm sure it's just my lack of experience with Javascript and jQuery.  Many thanks.

HTML

```
<form name="results-form" id="results-form">

    <input type="text" name="price-min" class="form-textbox-small no-radius defaultText" data="Minimum" title="Minimum" onchange="UpdateSearch()">

    <input type="text" name="price-max" class="form-textbox-small no-radius defaultText" data="Maximum" title="Maximum" onchange="UpdateSearch()">

</form>
```

Javascript

```
function updateSearch(){
    $.each($("#results-form").serializeArray(),function(){
        console.log("value: "+this.value+"     data: "+this.data+"     title: "+this.title);
       if(this.value == this.title){

          this.value = '';

       }

    });
    var FormData = $("#results-form :input[value!='']").serialize();
    console.log(FormData);
    $(".defaultText").blur();
}

$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".defaultText").focus(function (srcc) {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title) {
            $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $(".defaultText").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
            $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
        }
    });

    $(".defaultText").blur();
});
```

Console Output

```
value: 3     data: undefined     title: undefined 
value: Maximum     data: undefined     title: undefined
```

Comment: The "*default text*" is called `placeholder`, not `title` attribute.

Comment: `$(this)[0]…` - Ouch! Either use plain `this.title`, *or* `$(this).prop("title")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = $("#results-form").serializeArray();

$.each(arr, function (i, input) {

    var value = input.value;
    var $elem = $("[name='" + input.name + "']");
    var data = $elem.attr('data');
    var title = $elem.attr('title');

    console.log("value: " + value  + "     data: " + data  + "     title: " + title );

    // You can process the parameters here now
});
```